# How to perform a query by field using a predicate?

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

I can't seem to figure out how to properly write a NSPredicate that will filter a query to search by a certain field. I'm trying to search for the field titled "Location" and then search for the string in that field and see if the string "CA" matches up with the users string "currentState" (which is CA in this case, "currentState" is just the users location (placemark.administrativeArea) assigned in a string) and then only retrieve the records that match up with those filters.

[image]

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
func retrieveStateMoods(latestStateMood:String) {


    // Create query
    let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Location", "\(self.currentState)%K") // CRASHES HERE!!
    let sort:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
    let query:CKQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "State", predicate: predicate)
    query.sortDescriptors = [sort]
```

etc...

It crashes when I try to create the predicate. Here's the error code:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "Location"'
>   First throw call stack:

I know I'm not that far off but I just can't figure out how to format the predicate properly. I tried reading the NSPredicate example in the developer reference but it's all in objective-c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be:

```
NSPredicate(format: "Location == %@", self.currentState)
```

Comment: THANK YOU YOU ARE AWSOME